# OAuth2 flow for securing a REST API

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have Keycloak for authentication and authorization of multiple applications (a web page and a REST API). From my understanding the flow for the web page when using OAuth2 `authentication_code` grant type is as follows:

[image]

In this flow, in the second step (the one in red) the resource owner logs in because she/he were redirected to the login page of Keycloak. This flow is clear to me and is working well.

But, with the REST API I don't know what is the process to authenticate and authorize the user (resource owner), because there isn't a browser to redirect him to the login page of Keycloak. So, I tried with the `password` grant type and it worked, but then I realized that this grant type is deprecated. So I tried again with the `authorization_code` grant type but can't make it work. I am trying to get the token using the following request:

**URL:** http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/somerealm/protocol/openid-connect/token

**Body:**

```
username: someuser
passwoord: somepassword
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: someclient
secret: somesecret
```

The problem is that I am receving the following response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing parameter: code"
}
```

I know I have something wrong in the request (and in my understanding of OAuth2), but I have read a lot and can't discover what it is.

Answer (score 1):

API (backend) doesn't need any login flow usually. It just needs to verify token and then it executes requested operation or it denies it (response code 401 - problem with authentication / 403 - problem with authorization). It doesn't redirect to auth server.

Client, which is using API must obtain token before API request. It can be done by the frontend (e.g. SPA with `The Authorization Code Flow + PKCE`) and then frontend maintains  state (token refresh, error codes from the API, ...).

If you don't have any frontend, then procedure how to get token must be part of API specification. For example see swagger doc: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/

The `Client credentials flow` should be used `machine to machine` authentication, so it's not a solution if you need to know user identity.

Comment: `client_credentials` flow is the recommendation of the OAuth2 group to replace `password`. Just a FYI. Not just machine to machine anymore.

Comment: @Evert do you have any link/doc for that, pls? It doesn't sound like a good idea to have a dedicated client for client credentials flow for each user.

Comment: This was widely discussed on the oauth2 mailing list. I don't have a direct link to the discussion. This might require some hunting. 'dedicated client' is an implementation detail though, a OAuth2 server could map `client_credentials` to some other feature and not need something that looks like a 'client'.

The bigger point that the oauth2 group would make is, move away from this altogether and try to just use `authorization_code`.

Answer (score 0):

With the `authorization_code` grant type you *have* to spawn a browser in some way.

`password` is unfortunately deprecated, but the recommendation is to use `client_credentials` for these cases now. I hope this decision get reversed before OAuth 2.1 is released.

Comment: With client credentials grant type I would have to create a client for each user in order to be able to identify them?

Comment: @Jucaalpa this is what OAuth2 recommends as the replacement of `password`. It's possible that keycloak makes this hard. There's really no real drawbacks to using `password`, so I would recommend just keep using that until `client_credentials` is more usable.